# cross correlation of partially correlated signals

Tags: cross-correlation, signal-processing

I measure $x(t)$ and $y(t)$, two stationary random signals, and I want to find out if, and how much, they are correlated. What I'm doing is to plot the cross correlation `xcorr(x,y)`, and plotting it together with the cross correlation of randomly permutated versions of $x$ and $y$ : `xcorr(perm(x),perm(y))`, which would give the baseline, or background. The idea is that any feature of `xcorr(x,y)` deviating from `xcorr(perm(x),perm(y))` points to real correlations.

Do you find this correct? Would you suggest something else to do? Is there a standard procedure?

Comment: I do not understand the remarks in (1). How can $c(t)$ be a correlation, given that the notation suggests it could be any function of $t$? That would allow its values to lie beyond the interval of valid correlation values $[-1,1]$.

Comment: @whuber It was unclear, question edited. Indeed c(t) is an arbitrary signal, it's not the correlation itself. It implies a correlation in x and y.

Comment: **EDIT** I removed point 2 for now. Better to focus only on a good procedure to find the cross correlation.